# LEGO Bugatti Issues

Tags: technic, building, instructions, gears, wheel

This is my first post and my first LEGO set.

I recently built LEGO Bugatti Chiron with all the features working.

I am however having an issue with the rear axle/wheels.

The rear brake calipers fall off and touch the alloy itself. Also, one of the gears falls out if I push the suspension too hard!

[image: Close up of rear brake and suspension]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE! Bugatti Chiron is pretty big set and contain a lot of gears. Could you post a picture of the gear you have trouble with? In case it is hard to take picture of that particular location, perhaps referring to certain step in instructions could be beneficial to address your issue.

Comment: Should that be "red brake calipers" instead of "*read break* calipers"? Or better still "***rear** brake* calipers". And also "rear axle/wheels" instead of "*real* axle/wheels"